# Intermediary tables for SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

To cure a performance issue, I redesigned a query into the following:

```
SELECT
    G.line_item_id
    , G.price
FROM
    mn_price_master_li G
    , (
        Select
            max ( G_ED.date_impl ) as "mximpl"
            , max ( G_ED.eff_start_date ) as "mxeff"
            , G_ED.line_item_id as "Id"
        FROM
            mn_price_master_li G_ED
        WHERE
            G_ED.line_item_id = '6314925' OR G_ED.line_item_id = '908200'
        GROUP BY
            G_ED.line_item_id 
    ) G_EF
WHERE
    G.line_item_id = G_EF.Id
    AND G.date_impl = G_EF.mximpl
    AND G.eff_start_date = G_EF.mxeff
```

However it seems to that Oracle doesn't like this one...

`ORA-00904: "G_EF"."MXEFF": invalid identifier`

But when I do this...

```
SELECT
    G_EF.*
FROM
    (
        Select
            max ( G_ED.date_impl ) as "mximpl"
            , max ( G_ED.eff_start_date ) as "mxeff"
            , G_ED.line_item_id as "Id"
        FROM
            mn_price_master_li G_ED
        WHERE
            G_ED.line_item_id = '6314925' OR G_ED.line_item_id = '908200'
        GROUP BY
            G_ED.line_item_id 
    ) G_EF
```

It does return me the expected table.

Why am I unable to select the fields as defined under G_EF and how would I fix this?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired resuls and an explanation of the purpose of the query. Very likely, your query can be rewritten to be more efficient.

Comment: `"mxeff"` and `mxeff` are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle this `"mxeff"` produces a *lower case* column name.

Drop quotes and re run...

otherwise you must *reference* the column in the same way

```
AND G.eff_start_date = G_EF."mxeff"
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue is the use of double quotes.  But your query has a lot of other issues and non-best practices. I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT G.line_item_id,
       MAX(G.price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY eff_start_date DESC, date_impl DESC) as price
FROM mn_price_master_li G
WHERE G_ED.line_item_id IN ('6314925', '908200')
GROUP BY G.line_item_id;
```

If not this, then something similar (it is not clear what `date_impl` is being used for).  No subqueries are needed at all.